# need a little change with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have 2 links like this:
http://www.site.com/report/4fbb14
http://www.site.com/4fbb14

so `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for them is like:

> /report/4fbb14
>   /4fbb14

I just need to get `4fbb14`

I have used

```
$r_url = str_replace("/","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

But I need it to work for both links, is something like this acceptable?

```
$r_url = str_replace("(/ or report)","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much simpler would be

```
$r_url = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

That gives you whatever was after the last forward slash

Answer (score 2):

**Using *regular expressions***

Looking for the value at the end of the string, coming just after a `/`.

```
if ( preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/", "http://www.site.com/report/4fbb14", $result) )
{
  $value = $result[1];
}
```

**Using `parse_url` and a simple `explode`**

```
$values = parse_url("http://www.site.com/report/4fbb14");
$parts_of_the_url = explode("/", $values['path']);
$result = end($parts_of_the_url);
```

Answer (score 2):

All the previous answers will work, except for php NoOb's, but if all the links will have the same format you can just do this:

```
$r_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$r_url = str_replace("report","",$r_url);
$r_url = str_replace("/","",$r_url);
echo $r_url;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the `4fbb14`

```
<?php 

$ex = explode('/', 'http://www.site.com/4fbb14');
echo $ex['3'];
```